# disallow some image folders

Tags: seo, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am making my robots.txt file. But I am a little bit insecure about how to make disallow Googlebot-Image. I want to allow the Google bot to crawl my site, except for the disallow I have made below. This is what I made:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:

Disallow: /courses/
Disallow: /portfolio/portfolio-template.php/

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: 
/images/graphics/erhvervserfaring/
/images/graphics/uddannelse/

sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Should the User-agent: `Googlebot` and `User-agent: Googlebot-Image` be written together, so it is this instead?:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
User-agent: Googlebot
    Disallow:

```
Disallow: /courses/
          /portfolio/portfolio-template.php/
          /images/graphics/erhvervserfaring/
          /images/graphics/uddannelse/
```

Comment: Be aware that `Disallow:` without a value is the exact opposite of `Disallow: /`, so it allows everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should write them separately along with the Disallow information. 
Also, you should copy the Disallow information too.

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /courses/
Disallow: /portfolio/portfolio-template.php/
Disallow: /images/graphics/erhvervserfaring/
Disallow: /images/graphics/uddannelse/

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /courses/
Disallow: /portfolio/portfolio-template.php/
Disallow: /images/graphics/erhvervserfaring/
Disallow: /images/graphics/uddannelse/
```

As a reference, you can see what [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt) and what [apple](https://www.apple.com/robots.txt) did in their robots.txt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And this still allow the rest of my site to get index?

Comment: Yes it does! You only told the agent to not index the following, but it will index the other entries it finds.

Comment: Perfect Thank you a lot and happy new year, I can also see in Search Console it is working perfect.